# How can I use the value of a variable in a class to set the value of another variable in the same class

Tags: dart

The code below doesn't work instead it shows what i want to achieve.

As you can see I want to set `text` to use the color that `color` is set to.

```dart
class AppThemeModal{

    AppThemeModal({required this.color});

    Color color;

    TextStyle text = TextStyle(color: color);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the instance variable before the object is created, but you *can* reference the parameter in the initializer list:

```dart
class AppThemeModal{
  AppThemeModal({required this.color})
      : text = TextStyle(color: color);

  final Color color;
  final TextStyle text;
}
```